# Why does "kubectl get nodes" time out?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have been struggling with timeout issues for some hours when i run
"kubectl get nodes" or "kubectl get pods"
I am running minikube on my local machine, no errors are equally returned.

Comment: Please edit your post and answer - format text, do not paste screenshots.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the issue is that i had deleted the docker container when i was cleaning up containers.
All i had to do was run "minikube start" and it recreated everything again.
Everthing works fine now

```
(base) libracoder@arete:~$ minikube start
  minikube v1.16.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...

  Docker is nearly out of disk space, which may cause deployments to fail! (91% of capacity)
  Suggestion: 

    Try at least one of the following to free up space on the device:
    
    1. Run "docker system prune" to remove unused docker data
    2. Increase the amount of memory allocated to Docker for Desktop via
    Docker icon > Preferences > Resources > Disk Image Size
    3. Run "minikube ssh -- docker system prune" if using the docker container runtime
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9024

  Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.0 on Docker 20.10.0 ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Verifying ingress addon...
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass, ingress
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
(base) libracoder@arete:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   9d    v1.20.0
(base) libracoder@arete:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
mongodb-deployment-6586d9cdd9-8rkxg   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   89         19h
nodejs-deployment-77767cd597-hz5qc    1/1     Running            3          19h
(base) libracoder@arete:~$
```

Comment: Your answer should be plain text PASTES as well (the image is extra gravy optional, but the TEXT should be there).  Search engines don't find magic strings on images (or as easily and reliably) as it does not plain text strings.  This is so future searches will find our answers as internet search engines index these pages.